# Syscall in android NDK

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, system-calls

I have tried to use the [this syscall macro for arm_64](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch/aarch64/syscall_arch.h)

It works with SYS_open, read and close. I can see the file content properly.

After that Android APK crashes with the following message:

> A/libc: stack corruption detected A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at
>   0x00007689 (code=-6), thread 32141 (Thread-2910)

Does anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] of this?  Code and how exactly you compiled it?  It's not obvious how this could corrupt the stack unless you created a buffer overflow by passing the wrong pointer to `read`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hey Peter, I was expecting answers from you in another thread (chat) I have written details there. I'm going to prepare a minimal example today.

Comment: I don't have infinite time (unfortunately).  If I get around to it, I'll add details to my answer on your other question, not buried in chat somewhere.  If your other question had said "C++" in the first place, I wouldn't have only given you a C answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes I know, sorry. But I need a really little help. Minimal code : https://godbolt.org/g/KFpQyf but it gives some register errors. I have tried this in Android NDK for arm_64 and it compiles

Comment: Can anybody help?

Comment: On Godbolt you were trying to compile AArch64 code (with registers like `x0`) with an ARM32 compiler.  It compiles fine for AArch64-gcc: https://godbolt.org/g/SgoqoE.  ARM32 uses `r0..r14` (r15 is PC, the program counter).

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, I can compile the code on my target successfully, but the problem is it crashes after execution as I have mentioned at the main question. Am I using wrong parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least one bug in the code on the Godbolt link you posted.  These statements lead to a buffer overflow (surrounding code and if() conditions removed.)

```
char buffer[2048];

    length = syscall_read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        buffer[length] = 0;
```

`buffer[length] = 0;` accesses outside the array if `sys_read` returns 2048.  As the man page says, **`read()` attempts to read up to `count` bytes**, not `count-1`.  This could account for your stack corruption if the array was allocated right below something important.

You have to leave room for a 0 terminator if you want to use it as a C implicit-length string instead an explicit-length buffer+size with `write` or `memcpy` or whatever.  Remember that file data can contain `0` bytes.

As usual, use a debugger, and make sure your code works with normal system calls as well as your inline wrappers.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the 3rd parameter of `syscall_read` to `sizeof(buffer) - 1` and the **problem remains**. Actually the file length is less than 1024, not even close to 2048. I still have stack corruption.

Comment: @Phillip: Did you `strace` it to make sure the system calls succeed?  Or comment stuff out until the problem goes away, then see what memory is getting stepped on by code for that line?  (Assuming the problem still happens with optimization disabled so each line is compiled to a separate block of asm).  And does the problem still happen if you call `read()` normally instead of your inline version?  I don't have any Android dev environment to test this on even if I wanted to.  Your question doesn't even have your code in it, let alone any info from a debugger, so IDK if anyone can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I have renamed the types and added faccessat before the openat and it started working properly :)

Comment: @Phillip: Adding `faccessat` is probably just a coincidence, with different code-gen hiding whatever bug you have.  Changing types could make a diff if they were wrong, otherwise just taking more or less stack space is again probably hiding a bug.

Comment: I will test it deeply and if I get any similar error I will add here the result. For now it seems working, I have tried getpid exit and open read write close calls 100 times and it seems OK